# In R programming language how to convert 0815A into a 24 hour time format

Tags: r

I have a column in which time is in the following format: 0815A. I need it to be converted into a time format.

I have tried `poxscit` but there are some errors.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `as.POSIXct` specifying the correct `format`

```
as.POSIXct(paste0(v1, "M"), format = '%I%M%p')
#[1] "2016-07-27 08:15:00 IST" "2016-07-27 21:20:00 IST"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("0815A", "0920P")
```